# On what criteria Merge Accounts auto select the Master Record

Tags: account, duplicate-management, merge

[image]

***Note:*** 
From my observation it doesnt check Master Record based on the most number of fields populated. And also not because of the oldest Account record in merge.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default master record is the oldest record, but you can change it.